# Is there a trait in Rust that allows folding by groups without experimental features like coroutines?

Tags: rust, iterator, delimiter, yield

I would like to avoid experimental features so I am considering other options before generators.

I have a vector `v` which is delimited into groups by 0. The sum of these delimited groups can be accumulated through a for loop or an iterator:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![55, 23, 75, 0, 12, 34, 0, 97, 71, 23, 0];

    // for loop
    let mut acc = 0;

    for &vi in &v {
        acc += vi;

        if vi == 0 {
            println!("for yield {}", acc);
            acc = 0;
        }
    }

    // iter 'loop'
    v.iter()
        .scan(0, |acc, &vi| {
            *acc += vi;
            Some(if vi == 0 {
                let total = *acc;
                *acc = 0;
                Some(total)
            } else {
                None
            })
        })
        .filter_map(|acc| acc)
        .for_each(|acc| println!("iter yield {:?}", acc));
}
```

`scan` is used as an *ad hoc* coroutine which returns `Some(value)` when the iterator has produced a value and `None` when the iterator is still processing. `None` is filtered out and the sums are printed.

The example above is somewhat trivial as both operations produce the same result; however, my project requires digesting a stream of data (cannot be collected into vector) and conditionally folding them (e.g. a condition here could be if the `acc` is divisible by 10, instead of 0 delimited).

The folding condition itself is pipelined such that each pipeline may provide an iterator (think nested coroutines). I'd like to see if there is an alternative to `Iterator::scan` -> `Iterator::filter_map` whether they use iterators or not. Keep in mind, collecting the entire stream of data is not possible as the stream is potentially unlimited.

Comment: splitting into groups by zeroes should be as simple as `v.split(|vi| vi == 0)` and then you can use `.map(|g| g.sum())` or similar. I don't of a better solution for splitting based on the sum itself though.

Comment: @kmdreko Is there a way to do this with iterators? I am compressing a large stream of objects, and the compression itself is pipelined into 4 stages so collecting into a vector would cause undesirable latency. I see that the Split trait is specialized to String types. I wonder if I can avoid manually implementing that for vectors.

Comment: That extra information about how you're using it is key to making the question non-subjective. Currently you just have two different ways of doing the same thing, both of which work, and a vague request to make it "more idiomatic". If the code you have in the question does not meet your needs, it's important to include in the question *why* it does not meet your needs, and explain what kind of answer would be acceptable.

Comment: @trentcl I will add the extra information into the question. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Arguably, [`std::iter::from_fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.from_fn.html) might be simpler than `scan`+`filter_map`

Comment: I am confused by your use of the term "coroutine" in reference to `scan`. How is `scan` used like a coroutine here? A coroutine should either be able to suspend execution or switch it to someone else, and your code does neither, it's an ordinary subroutine. The title also refers to coroutines without explaining the connection.

Comment: The `filter_map(|x| x)` (which can also be achieved with `flatten()`) after the `scan` looks incorrect. While `scan`'s closure does return an option, `scan` directly returns it from `next()`, so the item of the iterator remains `T`, not `Option<T>`. To get the effect you want, you'd need to actually return `Some(Some(total))` and `Some(None)`. You never want to return the bare `None` because you're simply not using `scan`'s ability to terminate the iteration before its natural end.

Comment: @user4815162342 I will create another edit on the post clarifying its connection to coroutines. The similarity I saw with scan + filter_map to coroutines was that scan could “yield” values by returning Some(Some(value)). Additionally, to address your second comment, the function already does return Some(Some(total)). This was perhaps bad coding practice, but the entire if else branch is wrapped by Option.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with either the `for` loop or the version with `scan()`. If I were looking for a clearer alternative, I'd consider using [`group_by`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by) from the [`itertools` crate](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/). This version is elegant and does *almost* what you need:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

v.iter()
    .group_by(|&&vi| vi != 0)
    .into_iter()
    .map(|(_, group)| group.sum::<u32>())
    .for_each(|s| println!("sum {}", s));
```

The problem is that it outputs the numbers 153, 0, 46, 0, 191, and 0. The 0s come from the fact that it considers the element 0 as just another group for which the key (result of the expression `vi != 0`) happens to be false rather than true. To fix this, you need to change `map` to `filter_map` similar to how you did with `scan()`:

```
v.iter()
    .group_by(|&&vi| vi != 0)
    .into_iter()
    .filter_map(|(filt, group)| if filt { Some(group.sum::<u32>()) } else { None })
    .for_each(|s| println!("sum {}", s));
```

Not perfect, but still slightly more elegant than the original formulation because it makes the grouping explicit.

Comment: My question was not correctly phrased. Take my upvote, but I will close out this question and repost the corrected version.